# Help finishing MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

users
- id
- name
- email

users_groups
- user_id
- group_id

There are a couple more fields but these are the ones I am trying to grab.

I am trying to return 'id, name, email, group_id'. I think I have the first part of the query right, I just don't understand how do the WHERE statement. Could someone show me the way please?

```
"SELECT users.name, users.email, users.id, users_group.group_id FROM users, users_group WHERE id='$user_id'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a [JOIN statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) here. Under the hood that's what your query does already, but actually writing one out is much clearer.

```
SELECT u.name, u.email, u.id, ug.group_id
FROM users u
INNER JOIN users_groups ug ON ug.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.id = $user_id
```

(I'm assuming `$user_id` has properly been escaped previously.)

Comment: I have made sure the $user_id has been escaped. Thanks for the help, thats perfect.